# Unable to use flash in Google Chrome

Tags: 12.04, xubuntu, google-chrome, flash, adobe

I have Xubuntu 12.04. I have tried everything. Google Chrome keeps giving me the `Could not load Shockwave Flash` message. Please help, I really need flash.

Comment: Google Chrome or Chromium?

Comment: Google Chrome.  I do have Chromium installed, and I don't mind which one I use but flash has the same problem in Chromium as well.  If chromium does better with flash, I can use it instead.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xubuntu 13.04